# Regex passing on regex tester but failing in qt

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I'm using regex to test if iptables have been set. Here is a stripped down version of what trying to achieve.

```
QRegExp rx_preroute(".*DNAT\s*udp\s*--\s*anywhere\s*192\.168\.13\.115\s*to:10\.5\.110\.123:7891.*");
QString out = "DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             192.168.13.115       to:10.5.110.123:7891";
qDebug() << rx_preroute.exactMatch(out);
//prints out false
```

However, if I do the same thing in the regex checker (http://regexpal.com/ ) it passes. Also it seem to me, by manually checking the pattern, that it should pass. Qt is running on the default regex syntax. I experience the same behavior with `setPatternSyntax(QRegExp::RegExp2)`.

Comment: Not sure, but may be you have to double escape, ie. `\\s`  and `\\.`

Comment: @M42 Be sure, because you're absolutely right.

Comment: @M42 That was it. Please form it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Alan: I've done it an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should double escape ie. `\\s` and `\\.` instead of `\s` and `\.`

Comment: Actually, there is no need to "guess" -- text in C++ inside double quotes should conform to the C++ standard ("2.14.5 String literals" in Draft N3797).